# Double Picker Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, interface-builder

I want to display the contents of a double picker to a label without hitting a button in the process.  Can anyone show me how this is accomplished.

I displaying calculations to a label and I want them to change as the user moves the picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a `UIPickerViewDelegate`, set it as the delegate of your picker, and implement `– pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` to modify your label how you want. The UIPickerViewDelegate protocol reference is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html). I would probably just set the viewController for the containing view as the delegate, but it depends on how your program is structured.

EDIT - example code added:

You declare a class as implementing a delegate protocol with <> notation as in the following:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

Then you can set the delegate of your picker view instance like so:

```
myPicker.delegate = myViewControllerInstance;
```

Or, if your picker is an ivar of the viewcontroller class:

```
myPicker.delegate = self;
```

Then, inside the implementation of your MyViewController class you can optionally implement the methods of the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol, and the corresponding messages will be sent at the right time. eg, `-pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` (if implemented in your delegate) will be called whenever the picker selects a value, and it will be passed the row selected and the component the row was selected in.

Comment: Is there anyway you could give me a little code example, I read this documentation but i'm not understanding it.

Comment: I'm currently unable since I'm on my iPad, but if someone doesn't post example code before I get back to a keyboard, I will.